# Adding C file causes pch error

Tags: objective-c, c, xcode

I have an `XCode` project with `objective-C` files.  If I add a new (empty) `C file` and try to build, I get a large number of errors right away while building a precompiled header, in ProcessPCH step.  The errors are "fatal error: Could not build module 'Foundation'", and things in `Foundation.h` not being found. Remove the C file and it builds again.  What is going on, and how to fix it?

**(XCode 5.0, OSX 10.8.4)**

*EDIT* I have tried Clean and Clean build folder, no effect.

*EDIT* Setting `Precompile prefix header = No` results in a bunch of syntax errors instead, in stuff like `NSObject.h` (and other Foundation framework header).

*EDIT* User Cy-4AH figured it out: there needs to be `#ifdef __OBJC__` around the *whole* pch file.

Comment: File names and actual error text will get you a lot more help

Comment: @uchuugaka: There are hundreds of errors. Clearly the build is mis-configured, the specific errors are not informative.

Comment: what is the *first* error you get?

Comment: Don't fear copy and paste. The errors may be enlightening to others.

Comment: Do you have preprocessor directives `#ifdef __OBJC__` in your's pch?

Comment: Just as an interim debugging step, what happens if you add a raw C file to the project, but with the prefix .m?

Comment: @Cy-4AH: This was it.  There was `#ifdef __OBJC__`, but it was not around the *whole* pch file.  Changing to around the whole file fixed the problem.  Post it as an answer?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Surround `#import`'s with preprocessor directive `#ifdef __OBJC__ #endif`

Comment: Thanks!  That was it.  I think I figured out why this works: the pch is included as a prefix into both C and ObjC files.  So my C files were getting Foundation.h which of course would never work :)